# Rename CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp WinForms in my program. When program running, it also create some process called CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess, can see in TaskManager.
I want to rename these process. How can I do this?

Comment: I advise against that, some `AntiVirus` programs find it suspicious that the exe has been renamed. The question it's self has been asked many times before, search the `GitHub` project.

Comment: For those wishing to rename the subprocess, it's now possible to implement your own (call it whatever you like). See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1149#issuecomment-225547869

Comment: Thank you, but it's still stealing focus :(

Comment: That issue is totally unrelated

Comment: I posted a question about this matter before, if you remember, version 49, and I hope this issue will be resolved in a newer version. Now I'm using version 45. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117125/c-sharp-chromiumwebbrowser-prevent-control-from-stealing-focus

Comment: That issue is not related, that particular issue needs to be resolved in `CEF`.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1856/