# C# ChromiumWebBrowser: Prevent control from stealing focus

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'm making a program that has a Form with a ChromiumWebBrowser in it. The navigation is done automatically. When webbrowser complete it's task, I'll dispose it, create a new webbrowser, add it to form, and load a new address.

But, when the new webbrowser was created and added to form, the program jumps in front of what ever other program is in the top with focus. Example: I start my program, press the button to start its task, open notepad to type some text and my program jumps in front of it when navigating to a new site.

Even when the window is minimized, it still steals focus from other open programs.

How do I prevent it stealing focus after it is created?

Comment: What version are you using? Are you using `WinForms` or `WPF`? (please include this information when you ask any question). Does the problem reproduce using the `MinimalExample`? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: I'm using ChromiumWebBrowser for winforms.

Comment: CefSharp.WinForms.47.0.3 and CefSharp.WinForms.49.0.0

Comment: @amaitland your example is browser emulator, not right for my case. My program auto load a website, and dispose it, and load an other website....

Comment: Fork the `MinimalExample` and apply your changes, demo your problem. I cannot help you further otherwise. By all means continue investigating on your own.

Comment: @amaitland this is my mini example, illustration my problem: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1KkAKXAmtVQdGtDd0NUYXF6TU0. please take a look at it!

Comment: As a general rule I won't download a zip from an unknown source. If you can upload to `GitHub` or another code sharing service then I'll have a look.

Comment: Even a `Gist` would probably do http://gist.github.com/

Comment: @amaitland this is my exam in github: https://github.com/giangcoi48k/mycefsharpexam/. Please take a look at it!

Comment: There were some focus related changes made in `CEF` in the `2526` branch (the branch `47` is built from). https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1700/windows-master-keyboard-input-does-not I believe that's the cause of this issue. If you rollback to `45.0.0` it should work normally. Second time I've seen this cause a problem. Will need to be fixed in the `CEF` project.

Comment: @amaitland thank you very much!

Comment: Found reference to the bug, someone has already opened an issue, you can track the progress at https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1856/

Answer (score 1):

As @amaitland said, [this looks like a bug](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1856/).

Workarounds I've used are:

1) disable the browser. This will prevent the browser from receiving mouse/keyboard input, but it won't "grey-out" the control.

```vb
Browser1 = New CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser(url)
Browser1.Enabled = False
```

2) Pass a callback .net function for when the page loads where you simply put the focus back to winforms by focusing on a label of your choice.

```vb
Label1.Focus()
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Your Form need set: this.Topmost = false;
   AND just set: this.BringToFront();
2. Add new browser to the form just like the function as follow:

   ```
   private ChromiumWebBrowser AddNewBrowser(FATabStripItem tabStrip, String url)
   {
       if (url == "")
       {
           url = OpenUrl;
           txtUrl.Select();
           txtUrl.Focus();
       }
       else
       {
           tabStrip.Select();
           tabStrip.Focus();
       }
       // ...
   }
   ```

Hope has help to you. Thanks !

Comment: Hi, having the same problem, could you explain what this means?